# Robotsetup with Segbot

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have already gone through the Robotsetup steps following the ROS wiki http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup.

Currently I am stuck in the step 3.1 Creating a Package, as I used roscreate-pkg my_robot_name_2dnav segbot (which I pulled from the github https://github.com/utexas-bwi/segbot). However, it displays: ERROR: dependency [segbot] cannot be found

Could anybody provide some suggestions on this problem? Greatly appreciate your time and help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/91976/robotsetup-with-segbot/) by [Lili Meng](https://answers.ros.org/users/2899/lili-meng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 286 on 2013-10-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here are a few things that might help solve the problem:

1. If you are starting afresh, I would recommend using catkin. Use `catkin_create_pkg` instead of roscreate-pkg
2. If you are using Groovy, use the segbot code from source that you will have to download in your catkin workspace.
3. The segbot code has been released as system debs in ROS Hydro. If you are using hydro, install the meta-package as explained below:

Command:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-segbot
```

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) with karma: 2871 on 2013-10-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1